# Why does this function not work when I put raw_input() as the argument?

Tags: python, return, nonetype

So I have this short program that is supposed to give the area of a shape. 
When I give a value to `which_area(x)` when I call it, it works fine. But when I put `raw_input()` as the argument, (and because I've put `print choose_area` at the bottom), the shell replies `None` after input.

I'm not quite sure what's wrong but I think it has something to do with the `return` statement and how I've put it.

Any help is appreciated :) Please and thank you.

From a beginning programmer.

```
def triangle_area():
    print "What is the base length?"
    base = raw_input()
    print "What is the height?"
    height = raw_input()
    area = 0.5*float(base)*float(height)
    print "The area of you triangle is:", area

def circle_area():
    print "What is the radius of the circle?"
    radius = raw_input()
    area = 3.14159*(float(radius)**2)
    print "The area of your circle is:", area

def square_area():
    print "What is the length of the side of the square?"
    print "(Remember that squares have equal sides, and if"
    print "you want to enter a seperate length and width"
    print "you have a rectangle.)"
    length = raw_input()
    area = float(length)**2
    print "The area of your square is", area

def which_area(x):
    if x == 1:
        return triangle_area()
    elif x == 2:
        return circle_area()
    elif x == 3:
        return square_area()
    else:
        return "You didn't pick 1, 2, or 3."

def choose_area():
    print "Calculate the area of which shape?"
    print "1. a triangle"
    print "2. a circle"
    print "3. a square"
    print "Enter a number to choose:"
    which_area(raw_input())

print choose_area()
```

Comment: Choose = raw_input; which_area(choose)

Comment: your area functions are not returning their results

Answer (score 0):

`choose_area` needs to return a value. Simple calculating the area isn't enough.

Change `which_area(raw_input())` in the last line of `choose_area` to `return which_area(raw_input())`.

Answer (score 0):

change your code

```
which_area(raw_input())
```

to

```
which_area(int(raw_input()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be few reasons depending on the python version you are using.

1. Due to wrong python version 
   if you are using the python version 3 or later version than that . it should be change to

   ```
   which_area(int(input()))
   ```

or if you are using bellow version to python 3.x then it should be (ex - 2.7)

```
   which_area(int(raw_input()))
```

eitherway be sure to use the cast because you are using input to take a number but

```
   raw_input() or input()
```

functions take input as a String

So according to your calculations if you want to get fractional numbers use "Float" if you want to get who numbers use "int" as a cast .

Answer (score 0):

To combine previous answers:

`which_area` requires an integer, `raw_input()` returns a string.  You need:

```
    which_area(int(raw_input()))
```

But, along with this`triangle_area`, `circle_area` and `square_area` don't return anything - they print a message instead.  You probably want to end these functions with something like:

```
    return "The area of your triangle is: " + str(area)
```

(note that I have just used simple string concatenation here - you could use either old-style or new style string formatting instead)

Answer (score 0):

the functions triangle_area, square_area and circle_area are not returning any values

```
def triangle_area():
    print "What is the base length?"
    base = raw_input()
    print "What is the height?"
    height = raw_input()
    area = 0.5*float(base)*float(height)
    print "The area of you triangle is:", area
    return area

def circle_area():
    print "What is the radius of the circle?"
    radius = raw_input()
    area = 3.14159*(float(radius)**2)
    print "The area of your circle is:", area
    return area

def square_area():
    print "What is the length of the side of the square?"
    print "(Remember that squares have equal sides, and if"
    print "you want to enter a seperate length and width"
    print "you have a rectangle.)"
    length = raw_input()
    area = float(length)**2
    print "The area of your square is", area
    return area

def which_area(x):
    if x == 1:
        return triangle_area()
    elif x == 2:
        return circle_area()
    elif x == 3:
        return square_area()
    else:
        return "You didn't pick 1, 2, or 3."

def choose_area():
    print "Calculate the area of which shape?"
    print "1. a triangle"
    print "2. a circle"
    print "3. a square"
    print "Enter a number to choose:"
    which_area(int(raw_input()))

print choose_area()
```

NOTE: raw_input takes promt as argument so you can do some thing like raw_input("Height :")